# MVC 3 - Model is Always Null in AJAX Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

All,

When posting form values via AJAX to my controller (/Contact/Process), the model is always coming in null and ModelState.IsValid is always false. Have no idea why the model is coming in null. The AJAX post is working and there are hydrated parameters.

Thanks

**FireBug**
Parameters
Contact.Email   xxx@example.com
Contact.FirstName   John
Contact.LastName    Doe
Contact.Message Hi there
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
contact Submit

**The View Model**

```
namespace GuitarCollector.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ContactViewModel
    {
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The Model**

```
namespace GuitarCollector.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        //Primary Key
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your last name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }



        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Message")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The Form**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="Status"></div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Process","Contact", new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "Status"}))
    {
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

         <p><span class="required">&#42; All fields are required.</span></p>

        <!-- First Name -->
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.FirstName) <span class="required">&#42;</span>
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Contact.FirstName)

        <!-- Last Name -->
         <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.LastName) <span class="required">&#42;</span>
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Contact.LastName)

        <!-- Email -->
         <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.Email) <span class="required">&#42;</span>
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Contact.Email)

        <!-- Message -->
         <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.Message) <span class="required">&#42;</span>
        </div>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Contact.Message)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Contact.Message)

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="contact" id="contact" value="Submit" class="btn"/> 
       </div>

    }

</div>
```

**The Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(ContactViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Contact.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        db.Contacts.Add(model.Contact);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Content("Success!");

    }

    return Content("Failure");

}
```

Comment: It'll be the DateTime

Comment: Try to change `<input type="submit" name="contact" />` name attribute to something else.

Comment: Thanks. That was part of the solution. I renamed the submit button name and id attributes to "contactForm" and had to also remove the hidden fields: Contact.Id and Contact.DateCreated. Please post your answer with an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give some other name to the `submit` input than your ViewModel's property name or remove it at all. I think you don't actually need it. In that case it won't be serialized and passed to the controller.

The model is coming as null, because the model binder can't bind value "Submit" to the  `Contact` property.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Contact.Id )
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Contact.DateCreated)
```

And asp.net mvc can not make a binding

Comment: Thanks, Good catch but still the model is coming in null